# html 5 canvas how to make a player jump (pure no frameworks)

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have a player, a background, and a land piece all set up. What I need is a way for the player to jump and land when I tap on the screen or onscreen button. I am making this for a mobile device. Here is the coding I have done so far.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> Testing Canvas</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function ()
  {

  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasOne");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var canvasbk = document.getElementById("bk");
  var contextbk = canvasbk.getContext("2d");


 var myelf = new Image();
 var myice = new Image() ;
 var mybk  = new Image();

 myice.src="iceland.png";
  myelf.src="elf1.png" ;
 mybk.src="bk.png";

 myelf.onload = function()
 {
 context.drawImage(myelf,40,55);


 }
 myice.onload = function()
 {

 context.drawImage(myice,0,150);

}    
 mybk.onload = function()
{

 contextbk.drawImage(mybk,0,0,canvasbk.width,canvasbk.height);

}


}

 </script>
 </head>
<body>

 <div style = “width:500px; height:500px; margin:0 auto; padding:5px;”>

 <canvas id="canvasOne" width="500" height="300"
  style="border:2px solid black; position:absolute; 
  left:auto; top:auto; z-index:2"></canvas>

  <canvas id="bk" width=500px; height="300px; style="border:solid black;
  position:absolute; top:auto left:auto; z-index 1"></canvas>

  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to do some learning, I won't spoil your experience with a coded answer, but you should check these 2 ways of making your character jump.

**To do a stationary jump (start & land on same coordinate) check out Easing.**

Easing lets your character jump fast, slow at their apex & speed up on descent.  In particular, check out easeOutQuart for ascent and easeInQuart for descent.

http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/effect/easing.html

**To jump from a starting point to a different ending point check out the quadratic curve.**

It draws a curve from an exact starting point to an exact ending point with the amount of "curviness" defined by a control point. The nice thing about a quadratic curve formula is that it naturally generates more points at its apex (more points means your character will start fast, slow at apex and speed up at descent).  Here's the quadratic formula which returns XY at a given time (T).

```
// get XY along quadratic bezier at T 
// (T==0.00 at start of curve, T==1.00 at end of curve) 

function getQuadraticBezierXYatT(startPt,controlPt,endPt,T) {
    var x = Math.pow(1-T,2) * startPt.x + 2 * (1-T) * T * controlPt.x + Math.pow(T,2) * endPt.x; 
    var y = Math.pow(1-T,2) * startPt.y + 2 * (1-T) * T * controlPt.y + Math.pow(T,2) * endPt.y; 
    return( {x:x,y:y} );
}
```

**BTW, there is a likely problem in your example code:**

Your bk.png image is likely your largest image since it fills the canvas.  It will likely take the longest to load and will be drawn last.  Therefore, your background will likely overwrite your elf1.png and Iceland.png images.  To correct this, check out an image loader so all images are fully loaded before you drawImage them on the canvas.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the book I read said if I have a separate canvas for the background it wouldn't get redrawn when I want to redraw the sprite.

Comment: Thanks for the getQuadraticBezierXYatT function, I was looking for that function for a whole day now!